# SQL select matching rows into two columns one row for each match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has the following information:

```
MatchID DataID Data 
1       100    info1 
1       101    info2 
2       102    info3 
2       103    info4 
2       104    info5 
3       105    info6 
3       106    info7 
3       107    info8 
3       108    info9
```

I need the result to be in two columns with a row for each matching ID to look like this:

```
MatchID DataID1   Data1   DataID2    Data2
   1      100     info1    101       info2
   2      102     info3    103       info4
   2      102     info3    104       info5
   2      103     info4    104       info5
   3      105     info6    106       info7
   3      105     info6    107       info8
   3      105     info6    108       info9
   3      106     info7    107       info8
   3      106     info7    108       info9
   3      107     info8    108       info9
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  The simplest will be to join the table to itself...

Comment: I have tried the join...but to make the example simple I used int for the IDs but I am using GUID's for the ID (and not int)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using a join:

```
select t1.matchid, t1.dataid, t1.data, t2.dataid, t2.data
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.matchid = t2.matchid and
        t1.dataid < t2.dataid
```

Comment: I have tried the join...but to make the example simple I used int for the IDs but I am using GUIDs for the IDs (and not int)

Comment: @JDaniels57 . . . You can still compare GUIDs using "<", so this should still work.  This is explicitly stated here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942(v=sql.100).aspx).